# How to read in a file extension and the perform a certain action, Java

Tags: java

so I have made a simple text editor built in Java; however, I need to know how to be able to recognize a certain file extension and then perform a certain action. To be frank, I have two files containing java and python keywords, the user should be able to save the file as .java or .py or open a .java or .py file and the keywords should be a different color from the rest of the text. I am confused as to how to read these extensions in.

Comment: Do you realize that file extensions are mere decorations? While a reasonable expectation would be that indeed a so called ".java" file contains Java code etc, this is nothing but an assumption? How will you handle failures?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the simple case is something like `filename.endsWith(".java");` to check if the filename has a .java extension. There may be other ways to discover a file type by mimetype, but I am afraid I do not remember that at the moment.

Edit: Maybe you should be careful to convert the string to lowercase before, to make it possible to recognize file extension even if it has a different case, no matter if your system has a case sensitive filesystem or not

Edit2: Actually I found that you can use java7 features to detect file type. If you have a java.nio.file.Path object, you can do:

```
String type = Files.probeContentType(filepath);
```

The type returned is the mimetype, for example text/x-java for java source code. Not sure how good it is, and not sure how it recognizes things, but I have tested that it works on example java and python source files.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it turns out I just decided to split my filename on the dot and go from there.